# Разбить строку на массив PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Есть строка вида {1}{2}{3}{4}{5}..{n}

нужно получить это:

```
Array(
[0] => 1
[1] => 2
[2] => 3
[3] => 4
[4] => и т.д.
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = '{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}';
$array = explode('}',str_replace('{','',$str));
array_pop($array);
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: последний элемент пустой будет?

Comment: Спасибо большое! Работает, но да, последний элемент массива пустой

Comment: @МихаилПоляков подправил

Answer (score 4):

Можно используя [trim()](http://www.php.su/trim) и [explode()](http://www.php.su/explode):

```
$str = '{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}';
$result = explode('}{',trim($str,'{}'));

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ещё вариант с помощью регулярных выражений:

```
$str = '{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}';

preg_match_all('|(?<={)\d+(?=})|', $str, $arr);
var_dump($arr[0]);
```

Comment: а зачем просмотры?

Comment: @teran чтоб обойтись без сохраняющей группировки.

Comment: по моему тут достаточно вообще просто `/(\d+)/`, результат тот же будет.

Comment: даже наверное без скобок

Comment: @teran да, можно упростить шаблон - конкретно для строки из моего примера можно просто получать одну и более цифр `\d+`. Я для уверенности написал шаблон на тот случай, если в строке будут стоять цифры в других позициях _(за пределами фигурных скобок)_